# Key Equivalent on NSButton Failing

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am attempting to set the key equivalent of a `NSButton` in a `NSWindow`. I am using the following code in my view controller's class:

```
someButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
```

However, when I run the application, pressing the key will not perform the button's action but play the system funk sound.

The window which contains this `NSButton` is presented as a window (not a sheet) using a modal `NSStoryboardSegue`. If I use the same code and configuration in my initial window, the key equivalent performs correctly. Would the type of presentation cause this problem? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Turns out this may be a possible bug. Key equivalents will not work when a title bar is deselected in the IB. I am now attempting to find a way to keep this selected with the same window appearance. Keeping the option selected and using the `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property on `NSWindow`, I have successfully removed the title bar but now I am unsure how to remove the window border. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out that bug! I was going out of my mind tyring to work out why the `keyEquivalent` wasn't working for a button on a sheet and it's precisely this. Enabling the title bar made everything work again (even though the title bar was never visilble because I was showing the Window as a sheet!) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to have the title bar disabled in your window? There's some unexpected behavior (hesitate to call it a bug) where keyboard events are ignored in a modal window if the title bar is disabled (even though the title bar isn't used in sheets).

Comment: I do as I wanted to remove the window's border. Any ideas? I hope this "bug" is reported

Comment: If you're presenting it as a sheet, this is unnecessary as the title bar is never displayed on a sheet regardless. So turn it back on and test; I'll bet it will look the way you want it to and work fine. If you also want to use the scene as a non-modal, then toggle the title bar in code in `prepareForSegue...`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm presenting it as a normal window and not a sheet and therefore I really need my window to not contain a title bar. Is there another way I can hide the title bar and subsequent window border whilst keeping the switch on? I'll update my question

Comment: I thought you said modal and assumed sheet. Sorry about that. More info is probably needed. Ex: do you override anything in the window controller or its content view controller?

Comment: I've updated my question. I do not override anything in my view controller